# RNFetchBlob android, first view and then download the image

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

Is there a way to open an image file (mainly jpeg) with:

```
RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(res.path(), item.mime_type);
```

and then allow to save the image, I'm trying on an emulator Nexus 4 and API 25 but both from the gallery and from the photo there is no option to save the image ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-native-image-view 
url: 
 https://github.com/antonKalinin/react-native-image-view

It provides feasibility to  custom render for footer and control types. There you can make a download button on click of button,  write a code for image download using RNFetchBlob.

Comment: thanks guys, both solutions are acceptable .. as soon as I finish I accept the answer I used ;-)